# Laravel 5.1 - pivot table between three tables, better option?

Tags: php, laravel, pivot-table

I have 3 tables: **Users, Languages and Levels**.

One user have many languages and level.

Example:

- Jorge speaking: English advanced, Spanish basic.
- Peter speaking: English advanced, Italian medium, French basic.
- Luis speaking: Spanish advanced, English advanced, Italian medium.

Table User

```
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id       | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name     | varchar(50) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| lastname | varchar(50) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Table Languages

```
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name  | varchar(50) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Table levels

```
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name  | varchar(50) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Pivot table

```
+-------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(11)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| user_id     | int(11)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| language_id | int(11)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| level_id    | int(11)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| created_at  | datetime | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at  | datetime | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

The question is, how create the pivot table with three tables (in the doc laravel the example is only with 2 tables) is possible with three tables?
How to relationship with eloquent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I have something in a project using three tables and as pivot, so I run:

```
Modelo User:

class User extends Model{

public function levels(){
return $this->belongsToMany('App\Level','name pivot table')->withPivot('language_id');
}

public function languages(){
return $this->belongsToMany('App\Language','name pivot table')->withPivot('level_id');
}
}
```

Modelo Levels:

```
 class Level extends Model{

    public function users(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User','name pivot table')->withPivot('language_id');
    }

    public function languages(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Language','name pivot table')->withPivot('user_id');
    }
    }
```

Table Language:

```
    class Language extends Model{

    public function users(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User','name pivot table')->withPivot('level_id');
    }

   public function levels(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Level','name pivot table')->withPivot('user_id');
    }
    }
```

I hope you serve this option that I use to access information from all three tables

use:

```
$user = User::find(1);
$user->levels->pivot->language_id;
$user->levels->name;
$user->languages->pivot->level_id;
$user->languages->name;
```

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo Anwar Sarmiento.

Comment: De nada estamos para servir

Comment: Add, for sync User -> language / Level
$languages_levels = [1 => ['level_id' => 4], 2 => ['level_id' => 3] ];
$user->languages()->sync($languages_levels);

Answer (score 0):

You didn't post your relationships, but you can create a separate model of your pivot table. So you can define the relationships with the user model, language model and level model in that pivot model.